# Fazendo um Get utilizando o Axios (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Estou tentando puxar uma lista de nomes vindo de um json (http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon) utilizando o *axios* porém não entendo porque recebo o erro

TypeError: Cannot set property 'pokemons' of undefined

Sendo que o meu console.log está retornando a lista corretamente, segue o código do meu componente Vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="w-cards">
   <div v-for="pokemon in pokemons" class="card">
    <h1>{{pokemon.name}}</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
      return {
         pokemons: {

         },
     }
 },

created: function() {
    this.buscaPokemons();
},

methods: {
    buscaPokemons: function(){
        axios.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
        .then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data.results);
            this.pokemons = res.data.results;
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que `this` no contexto dessa função de callback não é mais a  sua instância do Vue. Você pode usar uma *arrow function*:

```
.then( res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data.results);
    this.pokemons = res.data.results;
});
```

Ou guardar uma referência à instância do Vue antes:

```
buscaPokemons: function(){
    var vm = this;
    axios.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
    .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data.results);
        vm.pokemons = res.data.results;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```